# Git rebasing (squash) after creating new branch

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-squash

Suppose I have Commit history as follows:

```
a -- b -- c                  <-- Branch1
           \
            d -- e           <-- Branch2
```

Now I checkout to branch1 and squash commits `b` and `c` into x.

I expected something like this to happen.

```
a -- x                  <-- Branch1
      \
       d -- e           <-- Branch2
```

But on running git log on Branch1, it shows:

```
a -- x
```

and on running git log on Branch2, it shows:

```
a -- b -- c -- d -- e
```

now even if I checkout to branch2 and squash `b`,`c`, it won't generate `x` but some other commit hash.

So my question is, How do I squash those 2 commits properly such that it is reflected in all branches?

Also how do I fix up once I already did that?

Comment: I think you have to rebase Branch 2 on x (Branch 1) after that it should be all fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now I checkout to branch1 and squash commits b and c into x.

after that you still are on `Branch1` do the following

```
git checkout Branch2
git rebase -
```

**important note** make sure before doing `git rebase -` you were on the branch you need to rebase. In this case it's `Branch1`. if you changed branches why so ever first go back to `Branch1` so like this:

```
git checkout Branch1
git checkout Branch2
git rebase -
```